# Monodevelop D Bindings for Debian / Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, mono, ide

I want to install the D-Language binding for MonoDevelop but it does require MonoDevelop 4.x, which isn't available yet for Linux based systems. Is there any way I can get around this?

I tried manually installing Mono and MonoDevelop but that just ended up in a huge mess and a lot of errors.